# MySQL - function to change time in datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a column `permission_to` with datetime type with this value: `2016-12-31 00:00:00` and I would like to change this value to: `2016-12-31 23:59:59`. I don't need update row because I need original value but the modified value I would like to use in query to compare with another column like this:

```
SELECT
  d.id_machine
  IF(
    d.permission_from < '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    d.permission_from
  ) AS date_from,

  IF(
    '(HERE I NEED FUNCTION TO CHANGE DATETIME FROM 2016-12-31 00:00:00 TO 2016-12-31 23:59:59) > 2016-02-02 23:59:59',
    '2016-02-02',
    (AGAIN THE SAME FUCTION)
  ) AS date_to
FROM tbl_decision AS d
```

Is there any MySQL function to modify time in datetime without update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ADDTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime):

```
 SELECT permission_to,
        ADDTIME(permission_to, '23:59:59') AS new_permission_to
 FROM tbl_decision;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06cbe9/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║      permission_to       ║    new_permission_to    ║
╠══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ March, 02 2016 00:00:00  ║ March, 02 2016 23:59:59 ║
╚══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

When we are dealing with 'end dates', we usually use the day after and then we use the 'less than' operation to compare with this date.

example: instead of 2016-12-31, we are using 2017-01-01
And when we use < so we take 2016 up to the last moment.

```
SELECT
  d.id_machine
  IF(
    d.permission_from < '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    d.permission_from
  ) AS date_from,

  IF(
    DATE_ADD(d.permission_to,INTERVAL 1 DAY) > 2016-02-02 23:59:59',
    '2016-02-02',
    DATE_ADD(d.permission_to,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) AS date_to
FROM tbl_decision AS d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HOUR_MINUTE format in DATE_ADD function.

```
DATE_ADD(permission_to, INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `permission_to` is of type datetime, but always holds values like `2016-12-31 00:00:00` I would store it as a date column instead of datetime.

Anyway I would write your query as this:

```
SELECT
  d.id_machine,
  greatest(d.permission_from, '2016-01-01') AS date_from,
  least(d.permission_to + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '2016-02-02') AS date_to
FROM
  tbl_decision AS d
```

This would change your logic a litte bit, if you want to get all records for a single day, instead of this:

```
where
  datetimecolumn>='2016-01-01 00:00:00'
  and datetimecolumn<='2016-01-01 23:59:59'
```

(what happens if datetime is `2016-01-01 23:59:59.001`? MySQL now supports microsecond!) just use this:

```
where
  datetimecolumn>='2016-01-01 00:00:00'
  and datetimecolumn<'2016-01-02 00:00:00'
```